# python bad status line error

Tags: python, url, selenium-webdriver, automation, phantomjs

While I am trying to download a URL with urllib.urlretrieve on Python2.x,
I face this error message;

> IOError: ('http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line', None).

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

from selenium import webdriver

import urllib
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.get("here is the url info")
print(driver.page_source)

contents = driver.page_source


soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
a = soup.find(href = re.compile("xlsx"))
print (a)

b =  str(a)

web = "http://www. here I but url" + b[9:76] + b[80:130]
print(web)

urllib.urlretrieve(web)
```

Questions;

1. How can I get rid of the error?
2. Is there any way to download an Excel URL link other than using urlretrieve?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the *full* error you get, including the traceback. This contains important information that can often help us to answer your question. We also like to have a minimal runnable example of the problem - could you verify that hardcoding `web` to the appropriate value (and removing all the code before that aside from `import urlib`) gives the same result? We do also need to see the actual URL you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: @at which line you are getting this error, is it driver.get() ?

Comment: Thank you for having a look on that. I could solve the problem by deleting Python2 and 3 installed on my PC and newly install Python2 only.